# Not able to Node.js and MySql connection in opsworks AWS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to connect two layer in opsworks in aws

1. Node js app server.
2. Mysql layer

I have created one node.js app and deployed on s3 repository in AWS mysql connection detail code is in below format

```
exports.db = {"adapter":"mysql",

          "database":"DBname",

          "password":"xyz",

          "port":3306,

          "reconnect":true,

          "username":"root",

          "data_source_provider":"rds",

          "host":"localhost"

         }

exports.memcached = {"port":11211,

                 "host":null}
```

And actual code for connection is ...

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var mysql=require('./shared/config/opsworks.js');

app.get('/', function(req, res) 
{

 var connection = mysql.exports.db;

    connection.connect();

    connection.query('CREATE TABLE SAMPLE(PK_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,USERNAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ( PK_ID )); ',

    function(err, rows, fields) {

    connection.end();

    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});

          if (!err)

           {

          res.write('TABLE CREATED SUCCESSFULLY');

          console.log('TABLE CREATED SUCCESSFULLY');

          }
         else
         {
              res.write('ERROR');
              console.log(err);
         }

       });

        res.write('OUTSIDE QUERY');

    res.end();

});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(80);

console.log('Listening on port 80');
```

when i was click on public ip the code was not working , anyone can help me to correct the code

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. What do you want to happen? What is happening instead? What have you tried? Why did it fail? What error message did you get? Do you have any other information eg logfiles that can help us to help you narrow it down?

Comment: hello sir , i m trying to run one node js app on aws opsworks which are node.js app server type and also i m using mysql layer for store my data to in it  but when i was run that app it will not works and also it will not show any error

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you get the error "connection is not a function".
Get your script running locally first before you try it on AWS because your whole script doesn't make much sense...